# ListView don't scroll fine... but i use internal image very small...why?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-widget

sorry for my english ...
I have a problem, I have a listview that is populated of a cursorloader, everything works perfectly except for the fact that the list of images not flowing fluid, The images they are very small and are internal (assets folder), the codie is as follows:

CursorLoader:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) { //chiamato alla creazione, collega il cursore alla query che ci interessa
    final Activity activity = (Tema)getActivity();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://presidente.widgetclock.temi");
    String[] projection = { "_id", "titolo", "autore", "abbrevia", "time", "provider", "estensione"};
    String selection = "tipo = ?"; 
    String[] selectionArgs = { "numero" };
    String sortOrder = "time" + " DESC";
    CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(activity, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    return cl;
}
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) { //chiamato ogni volta che c'è un cambiamento, sostituiamo il vecchio cursore col nuovo
    adapter.changeCursor(c);

}
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) { //chiamato sul reset, nullifichiamo il cursore
    adapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

CursorAdapter:

```
@Override
public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    titolo = cursor.getString(1);
    autore = cursor.getString(2);
    abbrevia = cursor.getString(3);
    uri_provider = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5));
    est = cursor.getString(6);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img1_a);

    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            uri_img1 = Uri.parse(uri_provider+"/n/"+abbrevia+"/l/"+abbrevia+"_5."+est);
            imageView1.setImageURI(uri_img1);
        }
    });

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titolo);
    textView1.setText(titolo);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autore);
    textView2.setText(autore);


}
@Override
public View newView(Context view, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup arg2) {

    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutadaptermeteo, arg2, false);


    return rowView;
}
```

onCreateView:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new CursorNumeroAdapter(activity, null);
    lstListaProva.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i have insert da plus important part...
if i don't "setimageuri" all is ok..

what is the solution?
is it possible load only image are show in the dyspaly and reaload other image only when scroll is stopped? or what is other solution?

thanks...